What are Marketing Automation Ops & Marketing Automation Rep App Services, how they function? Is it feasible to remove these services to reduce costs?
Additionally, I need to know if these services are dependent on any of our key areas, such as:
Personalization
Forms
Storing contacts in xDB
Storing data in the reporting database
If these services rely on any databases that store relevant data, what would be the consequences of stopping these app services?

Both the marketing operations ops and reporting services becomes operative when there is any marketing automation plan on the Sitecore CMS or there are live events. Therefore before closing these app services, you can make sure following things are checked.

There are no marketing automation plans on the CMS. When there is a plan i.e. active and contact meets the entry criteria of a plan, marketing engine creates the contact enrollment.

There are no live events created in the Sitecore CMS. Any goal, outcome, or event definition item marked IsLiveEvent is submitted to the Marketing Automation Engine.



More details on the same can be found here.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

Can I get any conclusive documentation or articles around this ? I just wanted to make sure nothing breaks once we stop this services
